# JTextPane: Identifying Strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to identify Strings (Which means text inside double quotes) in my JTextPane using the following code

```
Pattern string= Pattern.compile("\"/\"/.*");
Matcher matcher = string.matcher(content);

while (matcher.find()) {
    document.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), matcher.end() - matcher.start(), textPane.getStyle("red"), true);
}
```

But the above code is not identifying Strings correctly. I think the pattern I gave is wrong. Please help me by correcting the pattern.

Thanks all! I really appreciate your help! Since all of your answers are correct, I am in a difficulty of selecting the best answer, so I gave each of you an up vote. Hope you don't mind it :)

Thanks again all! I really really appreciate it :)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792474/matching-text-in-quotes-newbie

Comment: Without the escapes and enclosing quotes, your expression corresponds to `"/"/.*`. It that what you intended? I don't see a reason for the slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right expression is this:

```
Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
```

Comment: Thanks Matzi:) I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 String s = "jsdfjh shfslfh \"ksfsdkflsdaf\" 2346237846 ufhusdhfu usfhsdfis \"sadhgbshad78hgshd\" jhsdjs";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"{1}[.[^\"]]*\"{1}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(s.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }
```

Comment: The {1} in your regex are superfluous. And can anyone help me understand how `[.[^\"]]*` in a Java regex works just as `[^\"]*`does?

Comment: Thanks Bitmap :) I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Borodin: In Java, a character class like `[^\"]` embedded in another character class acts just like it would on its own.  This is to accomodate Java's set-intersection operator, `&&`, as in `[a-z&&[^q]]` (any letter except 'q').  So `[.[^\"]]` matches `.` or any character that's not `"`--which, of course, includes `.`, so that part's just as redundant as the `{1}` "quantifiers".  `"\"{1}[.[^\"]]*\"{1}"` is exactly equivalent to `"\"[^\"]*\""`.

Answer (score 1):

The regex I suggest you use is `"[^"]*"`. Quoted and escaped, that comes to `"\"[^\"]*\""`.

So try

```
Pattern string= Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
```

but be aware that that won't correctly find strings that contain double quotes, so I hope you `JTextPane` doesn't contain Java.